# Error: ORA-00904: "SCOPES": invalid identifier in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

"Recently, I migrated my project from LoopBack 2.0 to version 3.0. There were no runtime errors. However, when I ran the 'api/getuser' endpoint, the following error occurred:

Error: ORA-00904: "SCOPES" - Invalid identifier in LoopBack.

For migration reference, you can visit: [https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Migrating-to-3.0.html"](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Migrating-to-3.0.html%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SCOPES" is a new column added to AccessToken model in loopback version 3.8.0. I believe this column is missing in your Database table "AccessToken".